# There was no endpoint listening at Error sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf

I have hosted my WCF webs services into public server and  consumed this service from the WPF application and this app is using around 2500 users for the Login purpose.Most of the time it is working fine. But in some case it gives the following error.

> “Error : There was no endpoint listening at  …….. that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action”

Any idea why this is happening sometimes. How can I solve this issue? Is it related to port was busy that time?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Are you hosting your WCF services on a web server (eg. IIS) on that public server, or are you hosting it through some other means?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider monitoring performance counters for your WCF service.

WCF has built-in performance counters that show system metrics associated with WCF Service throttling and security, in addition to the typical Windows counters (cpu, memory, etc.)

To enable performance counters, include `<diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>`
 in the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the WCF Service configuration file.
You can then add counters for “ServiceModel” at the Endpoint, Operation and/or Service level.

The following link provides additional information:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/08/11/wcf-scaling-check-your-counters/

Good luck.